In a bar visual when i click on specific bar other bars should disappear it should show the same functionality like slicer without any slicer
When we click on "Finance", as a common behavior its just highlights the Finance data, but I want the output as below.
enter image description here
enter image description here
As we all know this can be possible by filters, but is there any trick achieving this without filters, just by clicking finance from the first image.
tried with button, page navigation but don't want any selection and want the same functionality how slicer performs but without slicers and by clicking the bars.

I am not 100% sure I am understanding if you want to "drill down" or have another visual filter this one.
If you want to drill into the categories you can click the visual and then click the single down arrow (upper right controls after selecting a visual) which will allow users to drill down and drill up.
If you were asking how to make this visual get filtered down to a category instead of just the contextual highlighting, then you need to select the visual which you want to influence your target visual, then go to "Format" menu and "Edit Interactions" and then click the "filter" icon on the target visual (while still having the visual selected which is meant to influence the target).
